# Lists, Files and readlines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm stuck with this example. I don't understand why when I do `print(contenuto)` the result is `[]` but if I delete all the "FIRST PART" of the program it works and the result will be `['prova1', 'prova2', 'prova3']`.
Here is the code:

```
def main():
    ####FIRST PART####

    lista = ['prova1', 'prova2', 'prova3']
    outfile = open('prova.txt', 'w')
    nuovo = input("inserisci: ")
    lista.append(nuovo)
    for a in lista:
        outfile.write(a + '\n')
    outfile.close

    ######SECOND PART####

    file = open('prova.txt', 'r')
    contenuto = file.readlines()
    file.close
    x = 0
    for a in contenuto:
        contenuto[x] = contenuto[x].rstrip('\n')
        x += 1
    print(contenuto)

main()
```

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Change `file.close` to `file.close()`.  What you have is merely a reference to the function, rather than an invocation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.close()` not `.close`.  You aren't calling the close function, so the file isn't flushed to disk yet.

Better to use `with` so the file is closed automatically:

```
def main():
    ####FIRST PART####

    lista = ['prova1', 'prova2', 'prova3']
    with open('prova.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        nuovo = input("inserisci: ")
        lista.append(nuovo)
        for a in lista:
            outfile.write(a + '\n')

    ######SECOND PART####

    with open('prova.txt', 'r') as file:
        contenuto = file.readlines()
    x = 0
    for a in contenuto:
        contenuto[x] = contenuto[x].rstrip('\n')
        x += 1
    print(contenuto)

main()
```

Comment: OMG thanks, I had it in front on my eyes and I didn't see for many days.